# JQuery and PHP - Inserting multiple rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tried and tried multiple asked questions with solutions here, but all were not solving my problem.

This form uses JQuery to dynamically add a set of fields. The problem is that MySQL does not insert the set of data upon submission. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form action="new_purchase_order%20(1).php" method="post">
       Supplier
       <select name="supplier[]">
         <option value="">Select supplier...</option>
          <?php
            $get_supps = "select supplier_name from suppliers";
            $supplist = mysqli_query($db, $get_supps);
              //get suppliers available in the database
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($supplist)) {
          ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row['supplierID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['supplier_name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br /><br />

      <select name="item[]">
         <option value="">Select item...</option>
          <?php
            $get_items = "select name from raw_materials";
            $itemlist = mysqli_query($db, $get_items);
            //get all raw materials available in the database
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemlist)) {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['materialID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
       </select>
       <!--enter its unit price-->
       <input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Unit Price">
       <!--enter the qty of the item selected-->
       <input type="number" name="qty[]" min=1 placeholder="Qty" width="30px">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button addMore">ADD</a>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include("session.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

for ($i=0; $i < count($item); $i++) {
  $supplier[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $supplier[$i]);
  $item[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $item[$i]);
  $qty[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $qty[$i]);
  $price[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $price[$i]);

  if (count($item) >= 0 && count($item) <= 24) {
    mysqli_query($db, "insert into purchase_order_history values('', '{$item[$i]}', '{$qty[$i]}', '{$price[$i]}', '', '$supplier[$i]', 'Pending')");
    echo "Success";
  }
  else {
    echo "Error";
  }
}
}

?>
```

Basically it uses the arrays of item, qty, and price. My problem is that it doesn't insert anything at all despite no errors to the PHP. The query is:

insert into purchase_order_history values('', '{$item[$i]}', '{$qty[$i]}', '{$price[$i]}', '', '$supplier[$i]', 'Pending');

EDIT: Here's the JQuery code:

```
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap js library -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  //group add limit
  var maxGroup = 24;
  //add more fields group
  $(".addMore").click(function(){
      if($('body').find('.form').length < maxGroup){
          var fieldHTML = '<div 
  class="form">'+$(".formCopy").html()+'</div>';
          $('body').find('.form:last').after(fieldHTML);
      }else{
          alert('Only '+maxGroup+' items are allowed.');
      }
  });

  //remove fields group
  $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
      $(this).parents(".form").remove();
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Is there an error with the query itself? Or is it the array coding that causes the problem?

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and add jQuery and HTML without ANY php in a [mcve], then we can see what serialize will do with your form. You did not post any jQuery. Also NEVER call anything in a form `name="submit"` since it will hide the submit event handler if you want to submit the form using script

Comment: Also, use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection. Add error detection to the insert query. For debugging purposes, you could write a log file showing each query before execution, and the execution results. The log file could also contain a print_r of each input var so you can see what is sent to the php script. For debugging, you could copy/paste the query in phpAdmin to see if it's valid.

Comment: BTW, using **mysqli_real_escape_string** is not enough to prevent SQL Injection. Using a parameterized query and binding vars to each value place in your query will make it a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: did you check for `mysqli_error()`? What is the database table structure of 'purchase_order_history'? Is the first field an AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: What is the result of your debugging process? Do the right values arrive in php? Do they get sent correctly? Do you even enter the for loop and later the count-condition?